# WITH Clause - temporary table to create

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I want to create a temporary table.

```
select * from TFW_ARCHIVETRANSACTION 
    where TYPE = 'openAccountTransferLifeCycle' and STATUS = 5 and 
          to_char(substr(
              TRANSACTIONDATA, 
              instr(TRANSACTIONDATA,'<ns:CredentialFunction>') + length('<ns:CredentialFunction>'), 
              instr(substr(
                  TRANSACTIONDATA,
                  instr(TRANSACTIONDATA,'<ns:CredentialFunction>') + length('<ns:CredentialFunction>')
                  ), '</ns:CredentialFunction>') - 1
          )) = 'OpenCurrentAccount';
```

I am trying like:

```
with openAccountTransferLifeCycle_c AS (
    select * from TFW_ARCHIVETRANSACTION 
        where TYPE = 'openAccountTransferLifeCycle'and STATUS = 5 and 
              to_char(substr(
                  TRANSACTIONDATA, 
                  instr(TRANSACTIONDATA,'<ns:CredentialFunction>') + length('<ns:CredentialFunction>'), 
                  instr(substr(
                      TRANSACTIONDATA,
                      instr(TRANSACTIONDATA,'<ns:CredentialFunction>') + length('<ns:CredentialFunction>')
                  ), '</ns:CredentialFunction>') - 1
              )) = 'OpenCurrentAccount'
);
```

but it is not working.

Where is wrong?

Comment: Please use better tags for your question. You're not supposed to use the [tag:table] tag at all (it says so in its description), and [tag:temporary] doesn't really mean anything either. Use something like [tag:mysql] if your question is about MySQL or such; otherwise we have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Please also state what exactly you are trying to achieve. Is the second snippet supposed to create a temporary table? What tells you it is "not working"? Do you have any kind of error output? What did you expect the result to look like? What did it look like?

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to create is not temporary table,you are trying to create CTE which can be thought of like a view but only  it's not materialized and scope is immediate..

You are almost there except selecting part and make sure you add `;` to start of cte

```
;with openAccountTransferLifeCycle_c
 AS 
(select * from TFW_ARCHIVETRANSACTION
 where TYPE = 'openAccountTransferLifeCycle'and STATUS = 5
 and 
to_char(substr(TRANSACTIONDATA, instr(TRANSACTIONDATA,'<ns:CredentialFunction>') + length('<ns:CredentialFunction>'), 
instr(substr(TRANSACTIONDATA, 
instr(TRANSACTIONDATA,'<ns:CredentialFunction>') + length('<ns:CredentialFunction>')), 
'</ns:CredentialFunction>') - 1)) = 'OpenCurrentAccount');
select * from openAccountTransferLifeCycle_c
```